# Enable Flash in Google Android Mobile Vision API

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-vision

How I can enable flash in Android Mobile Vision API. I have found some samples that uses with old Camera API along with Camera Parameters. But seems to be those API's are deprecated.

I have found few similar question in stackoverflow as well, but none of them are giving any clue about how to implement the same using Vision API.

I tried to implement the same using Camera2 API, that time it is throwing an exception that, Camera is already in use.

Please help.